# How to create response from dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to create below response from dictionary:

```
['Employee1'] : List of skills
```

**Code :**

```
public class Skills
{
   public string Skill {get;set;}
}
var skills=FetchSkills(); 
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Skills>>();
dictionary.Add('Employee1',skills);
```

Now i am trying to create below response:

```
'Employee1' =
 {
    {"skill":"skill1"},{"skill":"skill2"},{"skill":"skill3"}
 }
```

I want **skill property in camel case in my final response**.

This is how i am trying to create response but not getting how to create expected response:

```
return Json(dictionary.Select
(

), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: just return the dictionary. it will serialize to the format u want

Comment: @Nkosi:I want my skill property in camel case.How it will camel case skill property??

Comment: Add [`[JsonProperty("skill")]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attribute on `Skill` property in `Skills` class

Comment: @Nkosi:Can you show me how i would use linq to create expected response from dictionary as doing this would affect other place so i just want in this method only

Comment: is the expected response suppose to be an array? also check link in last comment on how to use attribute

Comment: @Nkosi:Yes expected response will be an array

Answer (score 1):

Given class

```
public class Skills {
   [JsonProperty("skill")]
   public string Skill {get;set;}
}
```

and used like this

```
var skills=FetchSkills(); 
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Skills>>();
dictionary.Add('Employee1',skills);

return Json(dictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

should produce

```
{
   "Employee1":[
       {"skill":"skill1"},{"skill":"skill2"},{"skill":"skill3"}
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for your kind efforts but can you show me to create expected response with linq?? (just for my learning purpose please)